# How to allow some controllers to be visited not others in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, networking, windows-server-2008

I will deploy my project in IIS and WS 2008.

I want to know how can I allow some controllers to be visited just inside my network and block people outside to see it.

Comment: maybe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta

Comment: add attribute authorize.. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811617/mvc3-can-one-controller-require-windows-authentication-while-a-second-allows-an

Comment: [Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff398049(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke How does forms authentication fit this scenario?

Comment: @DavidG, Its a link to a basic walkthrough on using the AuthorizeAttribute to _Restricting Access to a View_

Comment: @StephenMuecke All that link says is to add the attribute, nothing more. I doubt everyone would automatically make the association. The link provided by lordkain does much more and gives a full solution.

Comment: @DavidG    you are right    this  link  has  nothing to do  with my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the Request.Url property to check if the request is coming from another domain.  Based on the url you can hide this.

Based on this

1. Either you check the url in controller action method or
2. Write Custom Authorization attribute